# check valueCounts in one col based on second column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

To check all the different values in a col, I can simply do this:

```
df['col'].value_counts()
```

but what can I do if I only want to consider rows from `df['col']` where another col `df['second']` has a particular value. Eg: `df['col'] == "YES"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by condition and by column name `col`:

```
df.loc[df['col'] == "YES", 'col'].value_counts()
```